# Firebase Storage really needs a user to upload files?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

Recently I started to learn and work with Firebase and I have a doubt with their Storage Service.

I'm just using Firebase Storage to upload files from my Android App. I'm not using Firebase Auth Service, because I use my own backend for authenticate users.

Firebase Storage is working and the files are being upload with success, but I'm receving a strange warning exception (that's not avoiding the upload to be success):

```
E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: firebase-auth is not linked, please fall back to unauthenticated mode.
```

I don't want to create users with Firebase, because I handle this in my backend...

Why I'm faceing this warning? If I need to authenticate users just to stop this warning, can I create a "Application Level User"? I don't need to authenticate separeted users for this because all files are shared among users...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage works with the Firebase Authentication SDK to help the Cloud Storage backend know who the active user is.  This is how Cloud Storage security rules work.  Without the linkage between these two products, you wouldn't be able to write security rules that allow or reject access to certain users.

If you're not using Firebase Authentication, then you can just ignore that message.  But this also means that you have to enable full read and write access to *everyone* at the path in your storage bucket that your users upload to.  **In other words, anyone in the world can freely modify your storage bucket, and that could become a problem for your app.**

If this isn't what you want, consider using Firebase Auth to do custom authentication with your backend so you can be sure that only authenticated (and possibly authorized) users can modify your storage bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When you say "anyone in the world" is really that? **Even outside my app?** I think my app can write in my project storage because of the "google-services.json" inside my .apk that tie my app with my firebase cloud project... Is really anyone including others apps can write there?? If this really true so it's a huge security issue on my app.

Comment: Yes, it is a huge security issue.  Anyone could use `gsutil` to modify your storage bucket, unless your security rules prevent it by requiring authentication.

Comment: Wow! Sure? Using Firebase Auhentication is the ONLY way to protect my storage bucket?

Comment: You could write other types of security rules that limit what can be done in your bucket, but those rules wouldn't stop some random person who knows the name of your bucket from operating within those rules.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/

Comment: Really thank you for warning me this! Do you know if I could create just a "aplication user" with Firebase Auth? So I could authenticate this user all the time that I need to upload files... I can't create a Firebase user for each of my app user

Comment: That's not going to work.  You need to bridge Firebase auth to your own auth system with custom tokens.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Comment: @DougStevenson Isnt it possible to have a server handle this? something like this: Make request to own server-->server validates origin-->server writes/read data using admin sdk.

Comment: If you want a discussion about Firebase products, please post to firebase-talk.  Stack Overflow is not the best place for that.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Comment: @DougStevenson searching I found that I could use Anonymous Auth. Maybe that could be a simple solution for my case. What do you think?